# Center TextBoxFor with icon in column

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, input

I am trying to create a centralized login form, but with the code below the input text is aligned to the left and the icon to the right:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "E-mail" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The input size is set to 280px (bootstrap default in the Site.css file) and I would not like to change it. See in the image below the result, I would like to know how to join the input and the icon, and that the two were in the center of the column.

[image]

I got the expected result as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <div align="center">
                            <div class="input-group" style="max-width: 280px">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "E-mail" })
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bocask8/5dm0jzqh/2/)

Comment: You need to change the input width to 100%;

Comment: As I mentioned, this I would not want to do.

Comment: Oh didn't understand what you meant. the form is in a "display: table" which will try to fill the container space. try giving input-group a "max-width: 50%". this could vary due to the width of the text-box.

Comment: I tried it responsively and it returns to the messed up view. I changed the it to "max-width: 0" or the size of the input field and icon added together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div style="width: 280px">
          <div class="input-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EMAIL, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "E-mail" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EMAIL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Put the width style in a div and not in the input `<div style="width: 280px">` ...input field... `</div>`

Comment: In this way they have come together, but they are not centralized.

Comment: @PauloBalbino What is not centralized? can you show that issue in your fiddle or image?

Comment: Your answer helped me with the result, but I joined part of it with another comment from the question

Comment: @PauloBalbino Yes I have removed the comment once I saw that. May be you should mark yours as the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "E-mail" })
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`ValidationMessageFor` render to **span** element and causes space between input and icon.

Result:

[image: Result]

**Edit**

If you do not want to change `css`, you can fix it by `JQuery` like this:

```
$('.input-group').find('input').removeAttr('style');
```

Please see **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/dep34fmk/)**.

Comment: It continues the same way.

Comment: @PauloBalbino I tested your code and added result to my answer.

Comment: @PauloBalbino I think you have a css that causes this.

Comment: @PauloBalbino Please test `<p class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.Email)</p>`. Does it change?

Comment: It does not change anything, even until I remove that line. However, as I mentioned in the question, the input has a fixed size of 280px

Comment: @PauloBalbino I think it's interesting bug in interaction between bootstrap css and microsoft default styles.

Comment: @PauloBalbino You can use `col-md` class to limit your input by size.

Comment: @PauloBalbino I added `JQuery` code to my answer. Please see this. Hope to help you.